# What is this shrub with red leaves on top with spherical seeds? (PNW)

Tags: identification, shrubs

I have this shrub in the front of the house that I'm trying to identify. Here are 3 pictures of it:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm in the PNW (Washington State), and this is pretty large (6-8 feet high). Trying to figure out what it is so I can properly take care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a fairly mature Pieris, possibly Pieris japonica, though there are other varieties - new leaves start out red and gradually turn to  green over time. Yours is very healthy so it doesn't look as if you need to do anything much to take care of it; it obviously produced a good number of flowers earlier in the year, hence the seed pods. Further info and images here https://landscapeplants.oregonstate.edu/plants/pieris-japonica

Comment: Thanks! That looks to be correct as far as I can tell.

Comment: Look for the flowers next year between about March through to early June, depending  on the weather where you live.. They may be white or pink... that will confirm for you.